# Build php_perl.dll failing

Tags: php, perl, build, compiler-errors, pecl

I'm trying to build php_perl.dll and am getting errors, but my understanding of building these extensions is limited (obviously). So i need to get this compiled, or, alternatively, point me to a pre-built php_perl.dll that will work with PHP 5.2.17. The http://pecl4win.php.net site is dead, and what little i can find at http://pecl.php.net/package/perl isn't much help either.

I've installed Perl (tried 64bit then x86), PHP (installed with XAMPP), and Visual Studio 6. Windows 7 64bit. PERL_HOME set to c:\perl.

This command

`msdev perl.dsp /MAKE "perl - Win32 Release_TS"`

Results in 102 errors, like this:

```
--------------------Configuration: perl - Win32 Release_TS--------------------
Compiling...
php_perl.c
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\sys/socket.h(72) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'win32_accept'
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\sys/socket.h(72) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\sys/socket.h(72) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 's'
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\sys/socket.h(72) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 's'
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\sys/socket.h(72) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\sys/socket.h(72) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
...
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\sys/socket.h(98) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\win32.h(420) : error C2079: 'Wservent' uses undefined struct 'servent'
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\iperlsys.h(1143) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\iperlsys.h(1143) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
Error executing cl.exe.

php_perl.dll - 102 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: There are syntax errors in the (named) files. Double check you've obtained the right source-files and they did not get damaged.

Comment: @hakre - thanks. I understand syntax errors, but i suspect that either php_perl is incompatible with later versions of PHP or Perl, or i have my environment configured wrong. Was hoping someone familiar with building (or obtaining) this extension would recognize the errors.

Comment: Report this error to [bug tracker](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?search_for=&boolean=0&limit=30&order_by=&direction=DESC&cmd=display&status=Open&bug_type=All&package_name[]=perl&php_os=&phpver=&cve_id=&assign=&author_email=&bug_age=0&bug_updated=0)

Comment: @Alexandr - forgive my ignorance, but is that the appropriate place for build problems in a 3rd party extension?

Comment: Apparently there [is already a bug report for that](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57421).

Comment: @vstm - thanks! I saw that earlier, but there's no resolution for PHP 5.2, and was hoping someone here had either gotten it to compile and/or had a DLL built for 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

No answer for this question?

I just resolved compilation errors for php 5.3.13 on Windows by slightly modifying the new 1.0.1 php_perl.c source code (line 31):

old:

```
#  define _WINSOCK2API_           /* using winsock.h instead of winsock2.h */
```

new:

```
#  ifndef _WINSOCK2API_
#       include <winsock2.h>
#  endif
```

For the compilation follow the tutorial from this page (http:/ /www.crazyws.fr/tutos/compiler-php-et-ses-extensions-sur-windows-SJ5GT.html), sorry for the french.

Basically install Visual Studio 2008 Express WITH SP1 (otherwise a build error occurs), then uninstall any 2008 Runtime, then install the Windows SDK 6.1 (2008 Server) to compile VC9 builds. I also used a Perl installation from ActiveState (version 5.8.0, ActivePerl-5.8.0.805-MSWin32-x86.msi, not tested with further versions).

Then download the php sdk and deps from http:/ /windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/, php sources, sources of extension from http:/ /pecl.php.net/package/perl, unzip directories as described in the tutorial, modify php_perl.c as above.

Then open the CMD shell of the Windows SDK and type:

```
setenv /xp /x86 /release
cd <root_directory>
bin\phpsdk_setvars.bat
cd <php_src>
buildconf --force
configure --help
configure --with-perl=shared --with-extra-includes="<perl_lib_CORE_directory>" --with-extra-libs="<perl_lib_CORE_directory>"
nmake php_perl.dll
```

I compiled my dll on windows 7 Pro 64-bit and tested it on my WampServer installation. The .phpt files in the sources of the extension are pretty self-explanatory on how to use it.

For info another version of the file is also available for php 5.4 on this github repo (https:/ /github.com/do-aki/php-ext-perl).

Sorry for the long answer, but the README file of the extension regarding installation on Windows is obsolete and there is no support which I found pretty lame.

Regards